# Pyspark: No such file or directory in hdfs

Tags: xml, hadoop, pyspark, elementtree

I am trying to parse xml file's using **pyspark**. My files are present in **HDFS**. I have written my code below but when i execute it, it is not able to identify the location. Please help - below is my code

**Code:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
filenme = sc.wholeTextFiles("/user/root/CDs")
def add_hrk(file):
   tree = ET.parse(file)
   doc = tree.getroot()
filenme.map(lambda(filename, content): filename).foreach(add_hrk)
```

**Error:**

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'hdfs://xxxx/user/root/CDs/Parsed_CD.xml'
```

I want to mention that i am using **wholeTextFiles** because in the function **ET.parse** i have to mention the path of the file that i am currently trying to process. Please suggest as i am not finding any solutions. I have checked the file exists in hdfs but it is throwing that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ElementTree` library expects files to be available on local filesystem. That is why you shold use rather [fromstring](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring), for example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
filenme = sc.wholeTextFiles("/user/root/CDs")
def add_hrk(content):
   tree = ET.fromstring(content)
   doc = tree.getroot()

filenme.map(lambda(filename, content): content).foreach(add_hrk)
```

Comment: This helped me. Thanks for your reply. I am facing one more issue in the same code i hope you can help. i want to write the contents of all my xmls in hdfs for that i am using `dumpoff1 = Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-put", "-", "/user/cloudera/Demo/Demo.txt"],stdin=PIPE)` but i declared this line inside `add_hrk` that case my contents in the hdfs is getting overwritten. if i declare this outside the add_hrk i am getting error like file is not opend. I don't know how to acheve this please help.